# Redireccionar automaticamente a un controlador desde una vista .cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una aplicacion web mvc que solicita como pagina inicial verificar su **identificación** y si es correcta envia a la pagina principal, la acción cumple correctamente usando autenticacion via **Forms** y redirecciona a esta si se intenta ir directamente via url a otra dirección, pero al regresar a la pagina de login via url cuando ya se esta identificado, esta vuelve a mostrar los formularios de login. intente con lo siguiente, pero solicita la accion manual del usuario via link.

```
 @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Salir", "Index", "Home")       
}
```

- ¿Es recomendable redireccionar de una vista a otra vista directamente o el uso de un controlador es indispensable para evitar anormalidades?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En principio no veo cual es el problema de ingresar a la página de login una vez autenticado, se podria querer ingresar con otro usuario diferente, aunque es verdad que lo correcto seria realizar un logoff

Podrías en la view de login utilizar código servidor con javascript, algo como ser:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated){
   <script> window.location.href='@Url.Action("Home", "Index")'; </script>
}
```

de esta forma cuando renderice la view de login ingresara este script que ejecutara ni bien cargue, redireccionando a la página que definas.

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de Leandro te puede funcionar, aunque creo que lo ideal sería hacerlo desde el controlador:

```
    public ActionResult LogIn()
    {
        if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción es hacer que la página de inicio tenga un comportamiento diferente dependiendo de si el usuario está autenticado o no.

- Si el usuario **no autenticado** mostraría el formulario para introducir el usuario y contraseña
- Si **está autenticado** podría mostrar el nombre del usuario y dos enlaces, uno para cerrar sesión y otro para ir a la página de inicio

Una forma de implementarlo sería teniendo dos vistas distintas para cada caso `Login.cshtml` y `LoginAuthenticated.cshtml` porque cada una tiene un diseño diferente

En la acción del controlador tendrías este código:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return View("LoginAutenticathed");
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Algo importante que deberíamos tener en cuenta cuando desarrollamos es que hay que respetar los patrones.

En este caso el patrón [MVC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo%E2%80%93vista%E2%80%93controlador) implica que las peticiones pasan por el controlador, ahí se procesan y se hacen las operaciones oportunas y se preparan los datos (modelo) que te pintan en la vista.

Por lo tanto la redirección se debe hacer en el controlador como ha comentado Jorge Mauricio González y no en la vista